# Sonarqube Version 4.5.1 - The number of issues is not displayed

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I did the upgrade of SonarQube to version 4.5.1 and  Sonar Runner to 2.4 and it was done without any error. But running again the analysis of C# project, the nuber of issues is zero and it doesn't change.

Do I missing something or this is because I am missing a plugin?

Best regards,
SK

Comment: What version of the C# plugin are you using?

Comment: Hi Fabrice, the version of the installed C# plugin is 3.3

Comment: Can you check the quality profile that you are using? Are there rules associated to this profile?